# can the same parameter name be used as function param and local?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a function component - 'Task' , with parameter named id, and have this parameter saved in the state with the same name:

````
const Task = ({ id,text }) => {
    const [id] = useState(id);    // ERROR: identifier 'id' has already been declared
        
    return ( <div/>);
}```

I'm using Task like this: 

```class App extends Component {
render() { 
    <Task id='123' text='TEXT' />
}```
````

Comment: You got an error, means you cannot use same variable identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You are already defining in the scope the variable name.

````
const Task = ({ id:idParam, text }) => {
    const [id] = useState(idParam);    // Should suffice
        
    return ( <div/>);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
const Task = ({ id, text }) => {
  const [id] = useState(id);

  // ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
const Task = (params) => {
  let { id, text } = params
  const [id] = useState(id);

  // ...
}
```

which lead to redeclaration which produced error

Instead, you could destruct with another variable

```
const Task = ({ id: passedId, text }) => {
  const [id] = useState(passedId);

  // ...
}
```

or just use one passed parameter

```
const Task = (params) => {
  const [id] = useState(params.id);

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error aside, it looks like there's something wrong when we have to keep the prop in a state, I would probably skip the `const [id] = useState(id);` and use the `id` from the prop inside my component.

In case if `id` gets changed from the parent (`App`), then still the `Task` is referring to old value, just because initially we put the id in to state, and that state value not gonna change even if the prop gets changed

```
const Task = ({ id, text }) => 
    ....        
    return ( <div/>);
}
```